# invalid conversion from pointer to const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have the following class

File `Node.c`

```
std :: vector<NodeConnection*>* Node :: GetConnections() const
{
    const std :: vector <NodeConnection*> * output = &this->connections;
    return output;
}
```

file `Node.h`

```
class Node {
    private:
        std :: vector <NodeConnection*> connections;
    public:
        std :: vector <NodeConnection*>* GetConnections() const;
};
```

I am trying to convert the `vector connections` to a const pointer. However, I keep getting the error

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'const std::vector<NodeConnection*>*' to 'std::vector<NodeConnection*>*' [-fpremissive]
```

How would I go about converting it to a constant pointer that I can return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `GetConnections` is marked as `const` but returns a non-const pointer.

Instead you should return either by value, const pointer, or (my advice) by const reference:

```
const std::vector<NodeConnection*>& GetConnections() const;
```

Making a member function `const` means that it will not (and is in fact disallowed from) change any object member variables. When you return a non-const pointer, the caller could possibly change the returned value which conflicts with the constness of the function.

The line causing the error is the `return`, when you return a const pointer and the compiler has to convert it to a non-const pointer.

Comment: The method template `const std :: vector <NodeConnection*>* GetConnections() const;` works :)